# How long should a factory reset take?

Tags: factory-reset

I did a factory reset on my LG Optimus L70, and it showed a screen that said "Erasing..."

Shortly after, it showed the MetroPCS splash screen, and it's been stuck on this screen for over 2 hours. How long should a factory reset take?

Comment: Factory reset is already completed. You're now stuck at boot logo. Attempt to reset the device again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Factory reset has already been done. Now you need to take the battery of or reset the phone again. Thats the only way that its gonna work.

Comment: I did this, but it continues to gets stuck at the MetroPCS logo.

Comment: Then take it to the service centre. Probably your device is bricked. @badjr